# Android SQLite, how to get values from the column?

Tags: android, sqlite, get, cursor

I see how to get the column I want, but how do I get the data associated with that column on that particular row (given the rowID) using a Cursor object or SQLiteDatabase object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume c is your instantiated cursor

`c.moveToPosition(rowNumber);`

Comment: I want the value of the string data that I know exists in Row 2, Column "FullofStrings" for example. How do I get the string data at that intersection

Comment: You still have to move the cursor to the appropriate row. `moveToPostion(2)` then `c.getString(fullOfStringsColumnNumber)` unless you filtered out the appropriate columns in the query, then just do `c.getString(1)`

Comment: so I have to move the cursor to a row, then to a column, then retrieve the data that it has landed on?

Comment: Close. You don't need to move it to a particular column. Moving a cursor only affects the row the cursor is pointing at. After you have settled on a row, then you retrieve data from the column(s) that occupy the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

To get the specific value from the database column you need to use the collection framework class like ArrayList,VectorList etc.
For Example

`Cursor c=handler.returnData();`

```
ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<String>();
while(c.moveToNext()){
String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number"));
array.add(name);
}   
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "name"+array.get(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```